# What causes Launchpad to sometimes build binaries for only amd64 and sometimes build them for both amd64 and i386?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, x86

I uploaded the same package (ocaml-sexp, manually backported from [jammy](https://packages.ubuntu.com/ca/jammy/libcsexp-ocaml-dev)) for xenial, trusty, bionic, and focal [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejgross-h/+archive/ubuntu/coq-master-daily/+packages?field.name_filter=ocaml-csexp&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=?).  For the first three, Launchpad built both amd64 and i386 packages, but for focal, only an amd64 package appears, and this causes a dependency-failure of a downstream i386 package ([ocaml-dune](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejgross-h/+archive/ubuntu/coq-master-daily/+build/24104600)).  I uploaded the packages using my scripts in [JasonGross/coq-debian-build-scripts@bfa701f](https://github.com/JasonGross/coq-debian-build-scripts/tree/bfa701fdab6a3ca70d573b0ba0c0424a7f27c10d)
 with `cd ocaml-stuff; ./01-download-ocamls.sh; ./run.sh`.  (If it's useful the output log of `run.sh` is [here on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/VMcqJVw1).)

**Why did all but one distribution build an i386 package for ocaml-sexp, while all distributions built an i386 package for ocaml-dune, and how can I get Launchpad to choose consistently across packages to either build an i386 package (on focal) or not?**

Answer (score 1):

Canonical dropped full support for `i386` in Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan), which is why your 20.04 build didn’t include `i386`. Ubuntu only includes [a small selection of `i386` packages](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/community-process-for-32-bit-compatibility/12598/9) now, to provide support for some 32-bit workloads (notably Wine running 32-bit Windows programs).

As a result, there’s not much point in trying to provide `i386` versions of your packages for Ubuntu 19.10 or later.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't explain why Launchpad decides automatically to not build an i386 package for ocaml-csexp on 20.04, but at the same time decides automatically to attempt to build an i386 package for ocaml-dune on 20.04, which then fails because ocaml-dune depends on ocaml-csexp.  I guess I should amend my question slightly, then, and ask how to get Launchpad to be consistent about its decisions.